# running T-SQL in jupiter notebook, possible?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ssms

Lately i'm deeply involved in an a c# and SQL environment.
However in my mind i'm often still thinking panda jupyter notebooks.

What i really liked about jupyter notebooks is the possibility to include explanatory text blocks. And small result windows while making a investigation.

SSMS only has -- and /* to mark comments and 1 output pane, and therefore I find it complex to annotate relations and write good text in the editor to describe complex relations, i find ssms very limited when trying to explain to others and understand / learn how a complex DB works, requiring the user to memorize a lot (and thus drifting off frequently, a counter productive user interface).

So i wonder is it possible to run T-SQL directly (without panda) in a jupiter notebook ? so i can skip ssms altogether for annotation work. (only just copy final resulting queries into it).

Comment: do you need autocomplete?

Comment: no I can do without that

Answer (score 0):

would this work:

https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql

or with pandas integration:

https://github.com/pivotal-legacy/sql_magic